# how to parse json response coming from facebook in android

Tags: android, json

following is the response I am getting from facebook I want to parse it and and just get "data" :

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject
 {   
   graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state= {"data":[{"id":"544335545"},
   {"id":"546107794"},
   {"id":"567096700"},
   {"id":"584136789"},
   {"id":"586311098"},
   {"id":"590153482"},
   {"id":"592358568"},
   {"id":"593417823"},
   {"id":"593960664"},
   {"id":"608369788"}],
    "paging":{"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v1.0\/100000410265937\/friends?  
fields=id&format=json&access_token=CAAHqMWZBSop0BALK3izq04CPxR14mSsBvZAboLMm0h2EdGCiZBP2Q8B   YhDdVCY6tyGaZBAk1gQEacYZCrYobVZAsfdYvZBnqeK2l5OD0HnfdnKfZAiP2NmqcBn4bzS2AmPcxZA7pQVf5ZC2N4G    v3oUHmZBi77OcooZCiUQy97HEfqwnCLXH0yXzq7efv2hbrZBuxfI9Min2unWuuuE0KYbQb0mQ7ce22s2x8mdAaNgFHI   jQRJEAZDZD&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=enc_AeyIMOiqKCWGFRoCSHoxByFx8J0dzzfH6-   z1gL0LMcdjxqXhXBYlV7tYcFexltaF3AsUBykbDoRGR7cN1-NAYydA"}}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

please help to get this.

Comment: I know how to parse but bit confused with data I have got here

Comment: If you could share what you have done, then probably it would be easier to point out where you might be going wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSONObject  jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject japp = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Response");
JSONObject jst = japp.getJSONObject("state");
JSONArray jarry = jst.getJSONArray("data");

for(int i=0; i<jarry.length();i++){

 // your code
}
```

Comment: I got this exception: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 25

Comment: your json is invalid.

Comment: I am getting this response from facebook

Comment: check your response on this http://json.parser.online.fr/ .. it shows error.